# Proving a group $S$ is isomorphic to a single permutation group of $S$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-isomorphism

I am learning introductory group theory and want to prove the following:

Let $S:(S,*)$ be a group and $G:(G,*)$ be a group of whose elements are a result of a bijection from $S\to S$.

Prove $S\cong G$

Work: $G$ and $S$ are isomorphic if through a bijection $\gamma$, $\gamma(a*b)=\gamma(a)*\gamma(b)$ for $\forall a,b\in S$ and $\forall \gamma(a),\gamma(b)\in G$.

Let $a*b=c$. By the definition of groups, $c\in S$. Since $G$ contains the same elements as $S$, $\gamma(a)*\gamma(b)\in G,S$

Thus we can let $\gamma(a)*\gamma(b)=\gamma(c)$, which completes the proof.

However, this seems wrong so if anyone can help me that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $|S|=n$, then $|G|=n!$ if you’re allowing all bijections $S\to S$, so this would only be true for $n=1,2$.

Comment: The elements of $G$ are the elements of $S$ permuted once. Sorry if some of my notation is off or im missing something obvious.

Comment: Could you say more precisely what you mean by "the elements of $S$ permuted once"? My guess at the intended meaning: if $G=\{f:S\to S\mid f(ab)=f(a)b\text{ for }a,b\in S\}$ then $S\cong G$.

Comment: @stewbasic yes that is what I mean, I just don't know if my process was right or not

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is what you actually mean:

Let $\gamma_a(s) := as \ \forall s \in S$. Then $(\{\gamma_a : a \in S\}, \circ) \simeq (S, *)$

Then of course $f: S \to G, f(s) = \gamma_s$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Composition